# Custom Bootstrap ES6(module) for switch-toggle button in VU

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, module

I need to use the custom switch toogle in a Vue application.

https://github.com/gitbrent/bootstrap-switch-button

this is the button that fitts to me, but i have no idea how to register it in my component so that it can handle the data-toggle attribute.
`<input id="chkSwitch" type="checkbox" data-toggle="switchbutton">`

Comment: The bootstrap button and vue are seperate things. If you integrate the button you won't be able to read the state in vue normally. Try searching for a vue solution for your problem:example: https://github.com/euvl/vue-js-toggle-button

Answer (score 0):

Modern frameworks like Vue don't work well with direct DOM manipulation. If there's a choice, it may be preferable to use third-party Vue components instead of vanilla JavaScript widgets.

Data attribute won't work well because it's suited for static page where DOM elements are available on load.

This widget [pollutes built-in prototype](https://github.com/gitbrent/bootstrap-switch-button/blob/v1.0.0/js/bootstrap-switch-button.js#L215) which is considered bad practice and should be avoided. Since it also exposes API as a module, this is a preferable way to use it.

I expect it to be something like:

```
import Switch from 'bootstrap-switch-button';

...

<input ref="btn" type="checkbox">

...

mounted() {
  this.switch = new Switch(this.$refs.btn, { ... });
}

destroyed() {
  this.switch.destroy();
}
```

Other API methods can be called on `this.switch` when needed.

It may not work as expected because it directly manipulates DOM and can conflict with Vue.

Comment: It doesn't work like this, because of this
`if ( typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports ) {
 module.exports = SwitchBtn;
}`

Comment: I see. There's a bug in the package. This statement should be moved inside IIFE. Consider doing a PR. Currently a workaround would be to load it with <script> and doing `this.switch = this.$refs.btn.switchbutton()` instead.